# Setting up Apache ActiveMQ in Docker

Tags: java, spring, docker, dockerfile, activemq-classic

I'm trying to setup Apache ActiveMQ in Docker.

This is the dockerfile I'm using:

```
FROM ubuntu
LABEL owner="Naman Jain"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk wget curl zookeeperd -y

RUN wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/activemq/5.16.5/apache-activemq-5.16.5-bin.tar.gz --output-document apache-activemq.tar.gz

RUN tar -xvzf apache-activemq.tar.gz --directory /opt

RUN rm apache-activemq.tar.gz
```

After building the dockerfile and running the image ->

```
docker container run -it --name spring -p 8161:8161 -p 61616:61616 65e2b6f0f1529172ef8df15658347aa1898c653502f7cb507e798f12da43b81f
```

I started the ActiveMQ server ->

```
./activemq console
```

It has given the following output:
[image: ActiveMQ output]

But I'm not able to see the webpage on the browser:
[image]

I tried running the image using -p option but the webpage didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do a similar thing but with docker-compose, here's what i found until now:

```yaml
  activemq:
    image: apache/activemq:5.17.5
    hostname: "0.0.0.0"
    ports:
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    volumes:
      - ./jetty.xml:/opt/apache-activemq/conf/jetty.xml
```

I've taken the `jetty.xml` from the container itself. If you look carefully to your logs at the end:

```
..INFO | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/
..INFO | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://127.0.0.1:8161/api/jolokia/
```

Modifying the jetty.xml configuration, will do the trick.

```xml
<bean id="jettyPort" class="org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsolePort" init-method="start">
        <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
        <property name="port" value="8161"/>
    </bean>
```

> When a service listens on 0.0.0.0, it accepts connections from any network interface, including the loopback interface (127.0.0.1) and any external interfaces.